# Passing an array to controller via ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, post

So I am using AJAX to send an array to a controller

AJAX

```
 $('#concept').click(function(){

                       $.ajax({
                              url: 'http://localhost:8888/index.php/trial/getValues',
                              type:'POST',
                              dataType: 'json',
                              data: course,
                              error: function(){
                              $('#testing1').append('<p>goodbye world</p>');
                              },
                              success: function(result) {
                              var htmlStr = '';
                              $.each(result, function(a, b){
                                     htmlStr += b.qText + '<br />';
                                     });
                              alert("YEAH YOU WAS SUCCESSFUL");
                              $('#testing1').append(htmlStr);
                              } // End of success function of ajax form
                              }); // End of ajax call
```

course is an javascript array with two strings.

Controller

```
function getValues(){
    $playlist = $this->input->post('course');
    $this->load->model('get_db');
    $data = $this->get_db->getAll($playlist);//$var inside ()
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
    return $data;
}
```

Model

```
class Get_db extends CI_Model{
    function getAll($pList){
        $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE playlistID= '$pList[0]' OR playlistID='$pList[1]'");
        return $query->result();

    }
}
```

I have done hardcoding and can confirm that the controller, and model functions work as they should. The problem lies with the 'data' parameter in the ajax I think. I just dont believe the data is being passed to the controller in the correct way. I have endlessly search other questions, and I know there are questions similar to it, but I havent found a solution in this case.

Thank you in advance for any information you can provide :)

Comment: Try encoding as JSON first. I'm not sure if this is required, but it might make things more simple for you.

Comment: how and where would I do that

Comment: I am not sure if I'm missing something, but according to your code, the model is doing this in the query: `..where playlist = array(1,2,3)`. Shouldn't you be using other codeigniter function such as `where_in` or extract the array first?

Comment: Also I see, that you're returning data in your controller, not echoing. Only echoed data get displayed and returned to the ajax call

Comment: I am returning the data so that the $.each function has access to it and can display it. That part of the function works. @ISuthanBala

Comment: Huh? then which part doesn't work? I've been thinking you were not able to get data back so you can  insert it into the $.each function to iterate

Comment: Sorry, If I tell the model to grab everything from the database then the $.each function displays everything. So I know that part of the function works. It breaks down when I try to send data to the controller, then send that data to the model, then use that data to selectively grab from the database. So the problem is sneding the data from ajax to the controller. @ISuthanBala

Comment: Well I think that is the problem @ISuthanBala

Comment: I see, place the following code into the controller. `echo $this->db->last_query()`. That will display the last query, so tell me what that displays and then we can figure out whether we're actually passing in the data array?

Comment: If I add any echo statements inside the controller function, it breaks the ajax call and gives me the error message. @ISuthanBala

Answer (score 0):

You have to `echo` the JSON encoded data in the Controller instead of returning it. In the Ajax callback, you must then `JSON.parse()` the `result` before the `$.each(..)` call.

**Controller**

```
function getValues(){
    $playlist = $this->input->post('course');
    $this->load->model('get_db');
    $data = $this->get_db->getAll($playlist);//$var inside ()
    echo json_encode($data);
    // $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    // $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data));
    // return $data;
}
```

**Ajax-Call**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/index.php/trial/getValues',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: course,
    error: function(){
        $('#testing1').append('<p>goodbye world</p>');
    },
    success: function(result) {
        var htmlStr = '';
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
        $.each(jsonData, function(a, b){
            htmlStr += b.qText + '<br />';
        });
        alert("YEAH YOU WAS SUCCESSFUL");
        $('#testing1').append(htmlStr);
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. So when I integrate this code i get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o"  error. I am also afraid that when I did the hardcoding to make sure the controller and model worked, the array that I used was a php array. However, now I am trying to send a javascript array. I am wondering if that messes with the php coding I have done.

Comment: This would ne caused by the content of the '$data' then (when parsing). Maybe you could provide some more Info or even better a testsite/fiddle where i could look up whats wrong. The content of 'result' would be helpful as well.

Comment: Oh, and if did not comment the set_content_type(..) out, it is possible that you must not parse the result at the client side wich migth fit to your error message.